# I have a basic LED circuit with an STM32F030R8T6 which is not working and I cannot figure out why

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, stm32, breadboard, st-link

Apologies as this is a somewhat vague question but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my circuit/program and I have been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now.

I have this circuit I put together (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWWXg.jpg
) following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjzO1Iq64hw&list=PL6PplMTH29SEJhWqxhxkDKYPtw0C4mnNY&index=14).

I am attempting to get the LED in this circuit to turn on.

The breakout board has a STM32F030R8T6 on it and my code looks like this

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();

  //SET portC pin 6 (actual 37) as output
  RCC -> AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOCEN;

  //Mode Register - MODER
  GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER6_0;
  GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1;

  //Output type register - OTYPE
  GPIOC -> OTYPER &= ~GPIO_OTYPER_OT_6;

  //Output speed register - OSPEED
  GPIOC -> OSPEEDR &= ~GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6_0;

  //Pull up pull down register - PUPD
  GPIOC -> PUPDR &= ~GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6_0;
  GPIOC -> PUPDR &= ~GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR6_1;

  SystemClock_Config();

  GPIOC -> BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_6;

  while (1)
  {
//    GPIOC -> BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BS_6;
//    waitforamoment(100);
//    GPIOC -> BSRR |= GPIO_BSRR_BR_6;
//    waitforamoment(100);
  }
}
```

The resistor bridging the rails e and f is a 330ohm resistor (a little much for a green LED apparently but I still thought I would see something). I am sure that led diode is facing the proper direction. I can seemingly load my program onto the board using an STMLinkv2 and STM32CubeIDE throws no errors when I load the program on the board. I get the Download verified successfully message in the console. I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. I am fairly certain the leads of both the resistor and led are long enough and I am properly hitting pin 37 in my code.

Something that occurred to me while writing this. When I was putting this circuit together, I accidentally zapped one of the breakout board leads on the top side of the board. Is it possible I killed the chip?

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the voltage on the pin. And try using a different pin, in case that GPIO was zapped.

Comment: It's nearly impossible to see if the chip connections are correct or incorrect. Even if they are correct, it is impossible to see if they make good connection. And for deciphering which pin is which, we'd need the board schematics of the board, and that code can't be reverse-engineered to be correct without a reference manual, but access to BSRR is anyway incorrect but might not be a problem even if it should be fixed. Also if there is a chance of chip being dead from a zap, it might be the only reason it does not work.